# UITableView with variable width cells

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm curious how applications create this look, specifically the photo section and the 'skinnier' UITableViewCells. I haven't seen a delegate method for cell width so I'm curious how they are dynamically resizing the cells and putting the image view in the UITableView. Is this some common trick/smoke-n-mirrors/workaround?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if i were to guess, i would say that they have added a UIView with a transparent background, which has a UIImageView for the photo, and a tableView as a subView

```
UITableView
|-header UIView
| |-UIImageView
| |-UITableView
|
|-tableViewContents
```

Answer (score 0):

[UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943) has two properties named tableHeaderView and tableFooterView, you can add custom UIView or UIView subclasses for these properties.

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableHeaderView
@property(nonatomic, retain) UIView *tableFooterView
```